# pH ORP sensor esp12 esp82666

Tags: esp8266, hardware

I need to know if there is a sensor that mesure pH and ORP, I have already googled about this type of sensor but i found only AtlasScientific that commercialise this kind of sensor

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes there are lots.  You might try search for "Arduino PH Sensor" and "Arduino ORP sensor" you'll get a lot more hits for Arduino than ESP8226.
This might be useful:
http://www.instructables.com/id/ORP-pH-Temperature-Data-Logger/?ALLSTEPS